# GrapesJs CLI: modify webpack5 to add multiples entry js + scss

Tags: webpack, sass, grapesjs

i am trying to configure a plugin with multiple js entry point in my webpack;
[image]

Each JS contain the JS fuctions and import the style in scss format (that scss file will be process with a loader in webpack)

[image]

My goal is get something like this

[image]

already is working but if you open the vars.js file, is not generated correctly and also the (vars.js.map) is not generated, the rest of the files are perfect

this is my code code sandbox
you have to execute the build task to debug

[Example in code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/jcencina/bootstrap-xditor/draft/nameless-tdd?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9h5qnhn000cltfgfair3jns%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A8080%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9h5r4d800d23b6lkb73whui%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl9h5qxja00773b6llvdp9kqq%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D)

I am trying different ways to export this and nothing works fine
I am not a expert in webpack, i think is something about rewriting the (entry, output)...
Thanks for any advice or solution

Grapes Cli contains default config for webpack
if helps, this is what i get when modify the config

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution, in case someone needs

```
      output: {
        // ...output,
        path: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "./dist")),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        library: 'bootstrap-xditor',  //<-- add this line
        libraryTarget: 'umd', //<-- add this line
        globalObject: "typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this)"//<-- add this line
    },
```

i really don't understand but works so next..

[image]